# Render PDF on mobile phone

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, pdf

I'm currently building a website, and i've a link who redirect to a PDF, I'm using embed to render it :

```html
<embed name="B7CBBB19951D7E0EEF11ACD000AE9A05" style="position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0;" width="100%" height="100%" src="./path/to/file.pdf" type="application/pdf" internal id="B7CBBB19951D7E0EEF11ACD000AE9A05">
```

But, if I open the link with my mobile phone, i can't get any pdf, or i'm getting a button "open" pdf.. (not working)
I've tested with android and iOs, and sometimes it's working, sometimes it doesn't
Any idea or docs about this ?

Comment: it's trying to download it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=YOUR_LINK_IS_HERE&embedded=true"
style="width:600px; height:500px;" 
frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: That's maybe working but, i wan't to host my pdf, and not with google..
anyways, i've used an iframe as you, and now i can download it, ty ^^